# Running PyQGIS script in Windows

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I'm not able to run the following PyQGIS script in Windows (it worked perfectly in OS X):

```
import sys
import os
from qgis.core import *
import qgis.utils
from qgis.analysis import *

app = QgsApplication([],True,"")

# supply path to where is your qgis installed
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(os.getenv("QGISPATH"), True)

# load providers
QgsApplication.initQgis()

sys.path.append(os.getenv("QGISPATH")+"\\apps\\qgis\\python\\plugins")
import processing

# Load layers with precincts and zip codes
print os.path.exists("..\\external\\precincts\\USA_precincts.shp")

layer1 = QgsVectorLayer("..\\external\\precincts\\USA_precincts.shp", "precincts", "ogr")

if layer1.isValid():
    print "Loaded layer 1"
else:
    print "Layer 1 failed to load!"

layer2 = QgsVectorLayer("..\\external\\zipcodes\\Bnd_2008_q3_region.shp", "zipcodes", "ogr")

if layer2.isValid():
    print "Loaded layer 2"
else:
    print "Layer 2 failed to load!"

# Spatial intersection between layers, save it as a new shapefile
overlayAnalyzer = QgsOverlayAnalyzer() 
overlayAnalyzer.intersection(layer1, layer2, "..\\temp\\precinctsZipcodes.shp")

QgsApplication.exitQgis()
```

The initial lines run fine, but then the code is not able to load the shapefiles. The output from the line `print os.path.exists("..\\external\\precincts\\USA_precincts.shp")` is `True`, but then it prints `Layer 1 failed to load!` when checking whether the layer was loaded correctly.

Does anyone know why it does not run in Windows? I was even able to run it in the python console (only running the lines between `layer1 = QgsVectorLayer ...` and the second to last line).

Note: I originally had slashes instead of backslashes. I got two answers telling me that the slashes were the problem, but it wasn't: I changed them and the result is the same.

Comment: Do you get any path if you print the QGISPATH variable?  `import os` `print os.getenv("QGISPATH")` That could be the reason.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's your path delimiters. On Windows, use either double-backslashes `\\`, or single backslashes in a raw string, like `r"c:\foo\bar"`.

I often use scripts on both Linux and Windows machines, and typically handle the different paths by checking the platform and conditionally using certain path styles, something like this:

```
import platform, subprocess

# Check whether Linux or Windows
platformUnknown = True
currentPlatform = platform.system()
if currentPlatform == "Linux":
    platformUnknown = False
if currentPlatform == "Windows":
    platformUnknown = False
if platformUnknown == True:
    print("Platform unknown")

# Set path to GDAL command line tools.
gdalCL_path = None
if currentPlatform == "Windows":
    gdalCL_path = "C:\\Program Files\\QGIS Lyon\\bin" # GDAL 1.11.3 via QGIS
if currentPlatform == "Linux":
    gdalCL_path = r"/usr/bin"
```

EDIT: An even better way to handle this is to use Python's `os.path` [module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html), which will handle correct path parsing and writing of paths for whichever platform (OS) you're running on. You can also stick to always using Unix-styled paths, with `/` instead of `\`, and let Python handle these correctly on Windows, as it knows to do.

Comment: That's actually not the reason. As I told you python is able to find the file in the line `print os.path.exists("../external/precincts/USA_precincts.shp")`. I changed all the slashes for double backslashes and I get the exact same result. Also, it works fine in the python console!

Answer (score 2):

The problem was in the paths. I changed it to:

```py
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(os.getenv("QGISPATH")+"\\apps\\qgis", True)
```

and now it worked fine.

Comment: glad you got it to work! The cross-platform way to do this is to use `os.path.join` as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14962135/5158630). No need for slashes, backslashes or escaping. Let Python do the work for you :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Windows uses backslashes for paths, while unix-based systems use forward slashes. This simply means that Python cannot find the path to the shapefile since it points to a nonexisting location.

For instance this line:

```py
print os.path.exists("../external/precincts/USA_precincts.shp")
```

will need to be replaced with:

```py
print os.path.exists("..\\external\\precincts\\USA_precincts.shp")
```

Why the double backslash? In Python the backslash denotes an escape sequence, such as `\n`for a newline or `\t` for tabbing. Therefore a double backslash is necessary to produce a single backslash in a string.

Comment: That's actually not the reason. As I told you python is able to find the file in the line `print os.path.exists("../external/precincts/USA_precincts.shp")`. I changed all the slashes for double backslashes and I get the exact same result. Also, it works fine in the python console!